# CSS Font selector usage

Tags: css, font-face

We have implemented a font kit, but are still getting issues with how the font renders numbers. For some reason the numbers seem to float above and below their baseline giving them a "bouncy" look. We implemented the webfont kit and here is a sample of the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "interval_semi_bold";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("/common/fonts/interval_semi_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/common/fonts/interval_semi_bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/common/fonts/interval_semi_bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/common/fonts/interval_semi_bold-webfont.svg#IntervalSansProBold") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "interval_regular";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("/common/fonts/interval_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/common/fonts/interval_regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/common/fonts/interval_regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/common/fonts/interval_regular-webfont.svg#IntervalSansProBold") format("svg");
}
```

Question: Do the "" selectors behave differently then '' selectors with regard to how the browser interprets the @font-face declarations?

Comment: I don't understand the problem...

Comment: These are not selectors. `@font-face` is a rule; quotes are just quotes.

Comment: Sorry for not spelling out the selectors " is a double quotation mark, and ' is apostrophe or single quotation mark. Do browsers interpret these differently as CSS declarations???

Answer (score 2):

Single or double quotes are interchangeable in CSS and have the exact same meaning, and the property values they're used in will render the exact same way in every browser. It doesn't matter which kind of quotes you use. End of story.

If your font *is* working, but just the numbers look off to you, it's most likely that the numbers in that font are that way on purpose. For example, `Georgia` has a really low baseline for certain digits:

[image]

I wasn't able to find your exact font for testing, but you may need to choose another font that renders digits in a way that's acceptable to you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I searched w3 schools but could not find anything definitive on those two selectors. The odd thing about Interval Sans Pro is that for Interval_Regular you get the bouncy behavior, but not with Interval_light!

Answer (score 2):

The “bouncy” baseline is actually a specific sort of typographic numeral used for setting numbers in paragraph text. They're often called “old style” figures because they mimic the behaviour of lowercase letters with ascenders and descenders, making them less disruptive to immersive reading. Like lowercase letters, they also have a variable width. So, if you're using the numbers for a paragraph setting, this is good typographic practice.

On the other hand, numerals that don’t “bounce” are called “Lining” figures. They have a fixed, equal width that make them useful for setting vertical columns of numbers.

The CSS3 property `font-variant-numeric` allows you to choose old style or lining figures, as long as the font has both varieties within its character set.

More here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#font-variant-numeric-prop

Are you using [Interval Sans Pro](http://myfonts.us/td-D7kCMi)? That font does contain both types of numeral.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Yes, we are using Interval Sans Pro. I'll have to have my designer check whether both font-variant-numeric varieties are available with Interval Sans Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Double-quotes `"` and single quotes `'` can be used interchangeably in the selector.  It has no bearing on how the browser interprets it.

For more information on URI values, head over to the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Interval Regular vs. Light, the Pro version of the font contains the extended OpenType character set with lining and old-style figures. The standard version of the font only has lining figures; it's possible your Light font isn't the Pro version.